# Android Tracing a Java API back to jni

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to understand the interaction between the java and jni, so I decided to trace one of the java API, `public int write (byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes)` (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r1/media/java/android/media/AudioTrack.java#1699).

If someone would point out if my thought process is correct or not.

The method

```
public int write (byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes)
```

contains

```
return write(audioData, offsetInBytes, sizeInBytes, WRITE_BLOCKING);
```

so it can be traced back to

```
public int write(@NonNull byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes, @WriteMode int writeMode)
```

(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r1/media/java/android/media/AudioTrack.java#1739).

Inside that function, it has

```
int ret = native_write_byte(audioData, offsetInBytes, sizeInBytes, mAudioFormat, writeMode == WRITE_BLOCKING);
```

which calls the native method

```
private native final int native_write_byte(byte[] audioData,i nt offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes, int format, boolean isBlocking);
```

---

After I grep through all of the AOSP, I found that the only place that contains `native_write_byte` is in static JNINativeMethod gMethods[]

```
`"native_write_byte",    "([BIIIZ)I", 
 (void*)android_media_AudioTrack_writeArray<jbyteArray>` 
 (`https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android- 
 6.0.1_r1/core/jni/android_media_AudioTrack.cpp#1065`) 
 (`https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android- 
 6.0.1_r1/core/jni/android_media_AudioTrack.cpp#592`)
```

Now I want to find in which shared objects contains the native function, so I downloaded all of the files in /system/bin and grep through them, and only found one which is `libandroid_runtime.so`.

After opening the shared object in Ida pro, I found it by searching for the unique string.

So I'm thinking that when developers use the write function, they import libandroid_runtime.so and use write function which contains `native_write_byte` function which is a native function that calls to `static jint android_media_AudioTrack_writeArray`.

Is this the right way to trace back to the C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did most of the work correctly.

I don't know why you stopped at [android-6.0.1_r1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r1), the same CPP file is [available](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_media_AudioTrack.cpp#659) in **master**. This native method is implemented as a template specialization of a C++ function:

```
template <typename T>
static jint android_media_AudioTrack_writeArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                            T javaAudioData,
                                            jint offsetInSamples, jint sizeInSamples,
                                            jint javaAudioFormat,
                                            jboolean isWriteBlocking) {
```

You can study how this function works. Note that here, as typical for Android platform code, the JNI calls are wrapped with **nativehelper** headers.

*to find in which shared objects contains the native function,* you can look up the corresponding [Android.bp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/Android.bp) script.

```
cc_library_shared {
    name: "libandroid_runtime",
...
srcs: [
...
   "android_media_AudioTrack.cpp",
```

**grep** through /system/bin is not necessary, and could actually be misleading, especially if the library were built with obfuscation turned on.

> So I'm thinking that when developers use the write function, they import libandroid_runtime.so and use write function which contains `native_write_byte` function which is a native function that calls to `static jint android_media_AudioTrack_writeArray`.

Basically correct. In Java, we usually invoke `System.loadLibrary(name)` to *import* libname dynamic library, and we would say *«`native_write_byte` is implemented with `static jint android_media_AudioTrack_writeArray<jbytearray>()`»* rather than speak about a *call* from `native_write_byte`.

Android runtime is a bit different. It is [started](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp#1032) on system load and reused by all apps. This start [invokes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp#1448), among others, [register_android_media_AudioTrack(JNIEnv *)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_media_AudioTrack.cpp#1376), and that registers all native methods listed in the [gMethods](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_media_AudioTrack.cpp#1279) table which belongs to android_media_AudioTrack.cpp.

Comment: Do you know how the system determines native_write_byte came from android_media_AudioTrack.cpp?

Comment: How the system determines that the implementation is in android_media_AudioTrack.cpp? I have updated the answer.